# Get all parts as List of a String1 that are not contained in String2

Tags: java, string, string-matching, difference

I have read almost all similar topics but haven't found a working solution for my case.
Sorry for posting similar question again.

Let's imagine I have two strings:

```
String string1 = "this is  my string ";
String string2 = "this is not my string that I want";
```

In my case I want my *string2* to be equal to *string1*

To do so I need to remove **not** and **that I want** parts from *string2* while collecting these mismatchings.

As a result I would like to have something like this in my code:

```
List<String> mismatchings = ...; // consists of "not" and "that I want"
String string2Adjusted = "this is  my string "; // string2 after adjustment
```

Is there any util to do so, Or I might need to do some hard stuff with strings myself?

Comment: Split on spaces and diff the arrays. Regex won't help, or at least if it does then the solution will be nightmare-ish.

Comment: Yes, I thought about spaces but there can be very different cases and even differences within a word.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This compares at the word level, if it is not sufficient and you want to compare at the character level, you just need to change the split parameter to an empty string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "this is  my string ";
    String string2 = "this is not my string that I want";

    String[] str1Parts = string1.split("\s+");
    String[] str2Parts = string2.split("\s+");

    ArrayList<String> missMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (String part: str1Parts) {
        for (; i < str2Parts.length; i++) {
            String toCompare = str2Parts[i];
            if (!part.equals(toCompare)) {
                missMatches.add(toCompare);
                continue;
            }
            i++;
            break;
        }
    }        
    StringBuilder rest = new StringBuilder();
    for (int start = i; i < str2Parts.length; i++) {
        if (start != i)
            rest.append(" ");
        rest.append(str2Parts[i]);
    }

    missMatches.add(rest.toString());

    for (String missMatched: missMatches) {
        System.out.println(missMatched);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amit thanks for nice suggestion! This is really close however the problem is that in result I get an array of words split by space, and my last part 'that I want' is also splitted by space what shouldn't be.

Comment: @SerhiiKachan I see, please check the edited version

Comment: yes, thank you! That now works fine. While I was looking for a solution I also found another way to achieve this goal using third party library - I will post another solution of mine.

Answer (score 0):

After researching of existing utilities I stopped at:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.cowwoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>diff-match-patch</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

With this 3rd-party library solution the result is as expected:

```java
List<String> diff = new DiffMatchPatch().diffMain(string1, string2, false).stream()
        .filter(d -> d.operation.equals(DiffMatchPatch.Operation.INSERT))
        .map(d -> d.text)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(diff);
```